# Shadowing instance variables with local variables in Java

Tags: java, oop, variables, shadowing

I have read that " a variable is shadowed if there is another variable with the same name that is closer in scope". I found this Point class with a constructor as an example:

```
public class Point {
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        x = x;
        y = y;
    }
}
```

Then I created an object of the Point class in the CreateObjectDemo class below
and printed the value of the variable x.

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);

    System.out.println(originOne.x);

    }

}
```

After running the compiler, it prints 0. But why doesn't it print 23? I thought that **"x = x"** in the constructor would be like **"23 = 23"**. Did I misunderstand the definition of shadowing variables?

Comment: No, what it means is "the local `x` that's a parameter to `Point` is hiding the class member `x`."  So you are hiding one variable that is named the same as a variable in an outer scope.

Comment: You are right in that the x (23) gets value 23, but this value 23 is not stored in the class. You simply send it to the consctructor and forget it there. When you after creating a point want to print originOne.x, the value of that class variable gets printed (0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought that "x = x" in the constructor would be like "23 = 23".

Within the constructor, the meaning of the simple name `x` is *always* just the parameter. So the assignment `x = x` in the constructor takes the value of the `x` parameter and assigning it *to* the `x` parameter as well. The instance variable is never touched. (It's not clear what you mean by `23 = 23;`, so I can't tell whether or not that's accurate.) Basically, this is a no-op and some IDEs will give you a warning about it.

To force it to copy to the instance variable, you want:

```
this.x = x;
```

(And likewise for `y`, of course.)

Comment: But isn't the value of the parameter `x` equal to `23` after I created the object? If I print out `x` that takes the value of the `x` parameter(23), why does it still print out 0?

Comment: Nvm my comment, I get it now :) ty.

Answer (score 0):

`0` is the default value for `int` type variables, and as the warning says, you're shadowing the variables in the constructor so the object variable is never assigned to.

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
    x = x; //assign value of local x to local x
    y = y; //assign value of local y to local y
}
```

You need to use `this` keyword to refer to the object variables `x` and `y` instead of the local variables:

```
public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x; //assign value of local x to object variable x
    this.y = y; //assign value of local y to object variable y
}
```